# Why won't my nav lis display horizontally with floats?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm new to coding and trying to figure out why my nav li's will not display horizontally? I've tried a few things which I've noted in the code below.

The catch here is, I must use floats instead of flexbox.

```css
header nav>* {
  float: left;
  width: 7%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul li {
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*margin-left: 2px;
  display: inline; not working*/
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Courses</a>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
    <img class="icon" src="#">
    <h2>Tech Academy</h2>
    <ul id="SideBar">
      <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I have tried changing the specificity to a class or id and that hasn't fixed anything. I should also note that 'text-decoration' is not working for the li but is working for the a 'courses'? * border: box-sizing is also at the top of the css sheet.

[This is what it looks like on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ScDP.png)

I am very new to coding and this one has had me stumped for hours. T

Comment: You have set a very narrow (7%) width for the direct children of nav. The system can't fit the items in horizontally so it moves to a new line. Try swapping that 7% for 100% and see what happens.

Comment: I switched it to 100% which brings the nav li to a horizontal line but it moves the h1, form and a to the left and vertically. I tried moving the margins a little to bring them back to the center but still not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, spacings between attributes in html files have no effect at all on the browser display, and same for spacing in css files.

The second thing, I'm not sure why you don't want to use flex (it's handy here - you set the display of the parent attribute (ul) to `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` and it will do the trick).

But if you don't want to use it, there are 2 other tricks:

#1

```css
ul {
    display: contents; /* this will make the parent act like it doesn't exist - and then do whatever you want with the children*/
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="SideBar">
    <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>  
</ul>
```

#2 grid

```css
ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content max-content; /*instaed of max-content, you can assign the width you want for each li*/
}


li {
    margin : 5px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="SideBar">
    <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. I know, it's frustrating not being able to use flexbox. This is for an assignment and my instructor wants us to know how to be comfortable with floats in case we come across it at work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` to arrange them either `column` or `row`. Declaring `display: flex;` should apply what you're trying to do. See the snippet below:

```css
header nav>* {
  float: left;
  width: 7%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul li {
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*margin-left: 2px;
  display: inline; not working*/
}

#SideBar{
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Courses</a>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
    <img class="icon" src="#">
    <h2>Tech Academy</h2>
    <ul id="SideBar">
      <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

More on `flexbox` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this on css.....

```
#SideBar{
display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```css
header nav>* {
  float: left;
  /*width: 7%;*/
  margin: 0 5%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul li{
 width: 100px;
 float: right;
 /*display: block;*/
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 2px;
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav>

<h2>Tech Academy</h2>
          
<ul id="SideBar">
<li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
</ul>
  
</nav>
</header>
```

## The problem

- is you have used `width: 7%;` to `header nav>*`

## Weird one

- its weird that you have used `display: block;` along with `display: inline;`

## Solution

- I have commented the *The problem* and *Weird one*,run the snippet it should work

Comment: Using float is not a good solution

Comment: @Sfili_81 i do agree that using `flex` is better ,but asking to totally change to use flex *is not good*, **here i am solving simply why the code does not**